# Are native and progressive "smartphone web applications" domainless?

Tags: domains, mobile

I am a webmaster specializing in creating, maintaining and SEOing web applications of the subtype `websites` (or alternatively, `solely-web-browser-executed-applications`).

I have never created what is commonly named a "smartphone web application", such as:

> - **Native web application**
> - **Progressive web application:** A native application that can be executed both natively AND by a medium such as web browser and accessed from a
>     smartphone's `desktop-icon`;
>     The "mobile-website" UI version in a web browser execution is generally identical to the "smartphone" UI version in a native execution of this app

Both native and progressive web apps, per the definitions I have sufficed, can be downloaded from an `app store` such as *Google Play store* or *Apple Store*.

### My problem

Given native and progressive web apps are executed on the world wide web and its corresponding internet infrastructure, I have a problem in understanding if any such app should or shouldn't have a web domain, that is, if these are web domain based or web domainless.

### My question

Are native and progressive "smartphone web applications" domainless?

Comment: When you say "native web application" do you mean a smart phone app that takes the place of your website?   I can imagine a smart phone app that doesn't connect to any domain because all the functionality is contained in the app.   For example an alarm clock or calculator app.   But you are asking about smart phone apps that actually get data from the web, right?

Comment: Hello Stephen ; by `native web application` I mean to an application that is installed locally on the operation system of the smartphone (just as you would install Libre Office on Ubuntu) but it gets data in and out also by using the web.

Comment: I am not sure if it is correct to parallel Doom 1 (1993) which had single player mode *as well as a multiplayer mode* with a "native web app" such as "WhatsApp" ; both, in some modes, get input and output which is `web mediated`.

Comment: And both, are "domainless" ; to that I meant (yes, *Facebook, inc.* did built a WhatsApp website to better promote and market it, but it's not the app itself hence I would say that the app itself is domainless).

Comment: Based on your other questions, I suspect you are asking whether or not you *could* build such an app without having to buy a domain name.  (Even if such apps would typically use a domain name to fetch data.)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller well I tell you with all honesty --- there is no significant connection between these (I can understand why you assumed there is) ; it's a derivative issue I thought about when learning on the concept of "domained" and "domainless" web application.

Comment: Wouldn't you say Doom 1, only due to multiplayer, could be a "native web application running on an operating system"? Just as WhatsApp is a native web application running on an operating system `while` the only essential difference by mean of installation is that the former is installed not from the web and the latter is?